# Neovim and telescope:find files with two strings

Tags: neovim, telescope, telescope.nvim

I am using telescope with Neovim to find files quickly. However, when I try to input two search strings seperate by space, telescope does not list any files. How can I search for files with two individual substrings in their path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Telescope is a fuzzy finder, you don't need to separate search by spaces, just type all together.

For example, if you have a file named `some_python_script.py` it will appear as a result of the query: `somescript`

Comment: Thank you, that actually did the trick, I should have had that idea myself.